# How to install downloaded .sh file?

Tags: software-installation

I tried running this command in terminal to give execution permission:

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

It says cannot access file.

How do I do this?

Comment: Probably the classic one: you forgot the path to the file? (just type the command `chmod +x` followed by a space and drag the file over the gnome-terminal window)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) where you saved the file; ii) the *exact* error you received.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the script requires it be in a particular location, you don't "install" a shell script, you just save it where you want it, and run it. It would also be advisable to read through the script first (by opening it in a text editor like Gedit) to make sure the script is safe.

## Ways To Run A Shell Script

### 1. Execute Script In A Specific Subshell

In this approach you specify which shell to run, and the path to the script you want that shell to run. Since you are executing a shell, and telling it which file to run, the script doesn't need execution permissions, which is nice from a security standpoint. Your default shell may be aware of where the shell you're running is located, in which case you won't need to specify the shell's path. Unless there are spaces in the file/folder names you don't need to wrap the shell path or script path in quotations. Some shells may not accept just a file path, they may require specific options, and formatting, but the idea is the same.

```
 "/path/to/shell" "/path/to/script"
```

Examples:

```
"/bin/sh" "/home/user1/Downloads/script.sh"

bash /home/user1/Downloads/script
```

### 2. Execute Script In Current Shell

In this approach you use your currently running shell, and the path to the script you want that shell to run. Since you are executing the script directly, the script needs execution permissions. Unless there are spaces in the file/folder names you don't need to wrap script path in quotations.

```
chmod u+x,g+x,o+x "/path/to/file.sh"

"./path/to/file.sh"
```

Examples:

```
chmod u+x "/home/user1/Downloads/script.sh"

 "./home/user1/Downloads/script.sh"
```

Some things to keep in mind with this approach are that you may want to limit who can run the script. "u+x" gives the owner of the file permission to run it, "g+x" gives members of the group it's owned by to run it, and "o+x" gives everyone permissions to run it. The script will only work if it's compatible with the shell you are running. You only need to chmod the script once; in future you can proceed to the second command. You will only be able to chmod the script file if you have permission to edit that file. If you are not the owner of the script file, and do not have permission to chmod it, you can use Sudo to gain elevated permissions.

Examples:

```
sudo chmod u+x,g+x,o+x "/home/user1/Downloads/script.sh"

 "./home/user1/Downloads/script.sh"
```